# Decomposition of $SO(n)$ into $SO(2)$ and inversions

Tags: rotations, orthogonal-matrices

I remember vaguely that any $R\in SO(n)$ is orthogonally equivalent to the direct sum of rotations in $SO(2)$, e.g., there exists some $Q\in O(n)$ such that
$$
QRQ^T= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\theta}&-\sin{\theta}&0&\cdots&0\\
\sin{\theta}&\cos{\theta}&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&\cdots&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&0&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
However, I don't quite remember the proof anymore, so it would be awesome if someone could prove some sketches or hints.

Comment: What do you mean by "inversion", the geometrical transform such that $\vec{OM}.\vec{OM'}=k^2$ ?

Comment: I removed that due to the fact that since the determinant is 1, the inversions must come in pairs, and we know that any inversion in 2D, i.e., $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,-y)$ is just a rotation $SO(2)$ by $\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I now roughly remember the idea. Basically, you know that if were to extend $R\in SO(n)$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$, we know that the complex $R$ has at least one (possibly complex) eigenvalue in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Taking real and imaginary points, we see that there exists a 1-dim or 2-dim subspace $W$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is invariant under $R$. We can then further show that $W^\perp$ is also $R$-invariant and thus use induction to decompose $\mathbb{R}^n$ into invariant subspaces of 1-dim or 2-dim. Restricting $R$ to each invariant subspace and the statement follows.